# How should questions that just suggest to read a tutorial on an external site be considered?

Tags: discussion, answers

[There is a user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1919/soos) that in his answers keeps to suggest tutorials that are all hosted on the same site.
He replied to five different questions, and in all of them there is a link to the same website; one question was effectively about a tutorial, but that is not true for the other questions. In a question the answer is the following one (I report the link to the web site as plain text, here):

> Answer above fix this if you have a CKEditor module, but if you use Wysiwyg module you don't have that option (at least for now).
>
> Here is how to override these settings with a module in CKEeditor and TinyMCE in Drupal 7: Drupal 7 - How to change p to br in CKEditor and TinyMCE.

In another answer, the user repeats what already present in another answer given four months before (but with less details), and then it adds the link, which has been then removed.

> The line should be
>
> `strpos($edit['homepage'], "http://") === FALSE`
>
> I addressed this in the comments area here: 
>   `http://www.wdtutorials.com/drupal6/8#comment-32`

How is this considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *generally* considered [overly promotional](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion), though I would have to look at the specifics to see. Flag it for moderator attention is the best thing to do.

[Who wants to go spam hunting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99699/who-wants-to-go-spam-hunting)

Comment: I updated the question to include the link to the user profile.